# After upgrading my dependancies, I cannot build android on the simulator with the command "npx react-native run-android"

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

After upgrading my dependancies, I cannot build android on the simulator with the command "npx react-native run-android" but it builds if I build using android studio

Comment: Is there any error code shows?

Answer (score 1):

you can try in this way

```
- yarn start
- open android folder with android studio
- sync with gradle files
- run in android studioi
```